# Typewriter apostrophe in typewriter font for apostrophe symbol

Tags: punctuation, typewriter

Is there a way of producing a typewriter apostrophe (U+0027) in a typewriter font when an apostrophe symbol is entered in `.tex` document?

To give an example, I’d like `\texttt{'hello'}` to produce `'hello'` with typewriter apostrophes (U+0027) rather than `’hello’` with quotation marks (U+2019) currently produced by PDFLaTeX. There are command-based solutions that offer `\texttt{\something hello\something}` syntax, but there might be a way of using `\texttt{'hello'}` in a document and getting the desired result, perhaps through changing typewriter font encoding or by another trick. I’m willing to put into document preamble a code of any complexity.

`upquote` package delivers the result for verbatim environment. I'm looking for exactly the same functionality but for `\texttt`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: related: [How to make a real apostrophe or single-quote in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63345/579).  also [Typesetting single quotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50533/579)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A streamlined version of karlkoeller's solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp,upquote}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\active@text@prime{\ifin@texttt\textquotesingle\else'\fi}
\def\active@math@prime{^\bgroup\prim@s}
\newif\ifin@texttt

\regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}

\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\'
\lowercase{\endgroup\protected\def~}{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\active@math@prime
  \else
    \expandafter\active@text@prime
  \fi}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\'=\active}

% fix \@resetactivechars not to redefine the active apostrophe
\begingroup
\obeylines\obeyspaces%
\gdef\@resetactivechars{%
\def^^M{\@activechar@info{EOL}\space}%
\def {\@activechar@info{space}\space}%
}%
\endgroup

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\texttt{'hello'} `here the quotation marks are normal'

Also \verb|'hello'| works

And here is some math $f''(x)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @val Fixed: I always forget about `\@resetactivechars`

Answer (score 13):

This is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro{\oldtexttt}{\texttt}
\def\oldapostrophe{'}
\catcode`\'=\active

\makeatletter
\def\active@text@prime{\oldapostrophe}

% this trick was done by egreg in another answer of mine

\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}

\protected\def'{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\active@math@prime
  \else
    \expandafter\active@text@prime
  \fi}

\renewcommand\texttt[1]{%
\def'{\symbol{13}}%
\oldtexttt{#1}%
\protected\def'{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\active@math@prime
  \else
    \expandafter\active@text@prime
  \fi}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\texttt{'hello'} `here the quotation marks are normal'

and here is some math $f''(x)$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]