# Straight typewriter apostrophe (' instead of ’) in \texttt-environment

Tags: typewriter, apostrophe

How can I write `'` instead of `’` within the `\texttt`-environment?

I have stumbled upon several discussions, but not a single discussion has solved my problem. I do **not** want to write code! I just want to have a straight apostrophe when writing in the `\texttt`-environment. Plain and simple.

Some solutions I have come accross were successfull in writing a straight apostrophe, but only in Computer Modern Roman or Latin Modern Roman – **not** in Computer Modern Mono or Latin Modern Mono. But that is what I need.

I have also tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222346/typewriter-apostrophe-in-typewriter-font-for-apostrophe-symbol), but it did not work.

Comment: Why did that not work? Have you tried the exact example shown there? Please provide the code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler solution for `\texttt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\texttt}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_nemgathos_upquotes_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_nemgathos_upquotes_tl { '' } { \textquotedbl }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_nemgathos_upquotes_tl { `` } { \textquotedbl }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_nemgathos_upquotes_tl { ' } { \textquotesingle }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_nemgathos_upquotes_tl { ` } { \textquotesingle }
  { \ttfamily \tl_use:N \l_nemgathos_upquotes_tl }
 }
\tl_new:N \l_nemgathos_upquotes_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

``Normal `quotes' here''

\texttt{``Straight `quotes' here''}

\end{document}
```

[image]